# Azure Pipelines .net core 3.1 library with references to other libraries how to create one nuget package

Tags: azure, .net-core, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have Visual Studio solution with 10 .net core 3.1 library projects (let's call them CORE). One of them is a main project. It has references to other projects.

I want to have one nuget package (stored in azure feed) which I can use in my other solutions because I won't add all dlls every time when I need CORE functionality. I need to define Azure Pipeline to do that job. How to define that pipeline which produce one package containing all other references (dlls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build the NuGet package, you can provide `-IncludeReferencedProjects` switch to the `nuget pack` command, and the referenced projects will be added as part of the package:

```
nuget pack MyProject.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

Note, that according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#run-nuget-pack-to-generate-the-nupkg-file):

> If a referenced project includes a .nuspec file of its own, then NuGet adds that referenced project as a dependency instead. You need to package and publish that project separately.

I would suggest you get acquainted with [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package). There are more options to granularly control the contents of your package. The raw `nuget` commands that are referenced there map easily to the appropriate CI tasks.

Comment: It seems to make sense so I will adapt this solution to azure pipeline soon.